# Kentico v5.5 C# get document

Tags: c#, kentico

Im trying to get a document based on the aliasPath this is the whole aliasPath im trying to get /PPIS/Vic-Residential/SERE26 but i don't want to hard code the whole path i just want to use the last bit something like this "?/SERE26" Ive tried all combinations and cant find the correct wildcard statement for ends with.

```
CMS.TreeEngine.TreeNode nodeCur = TreeHelper.GetDocument(CMSContext.CurrentSiteName,
    "/PPIS/Vic-Residential/SERE26", "en-au", true, "CMS.MenuItem", false);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use % character for this purpose that covers any number of characters:

http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/appendix_b___path_expressions.htm